# Run SSH commands in Batch (Windows)

Tags: batch-file

I need to login to the putty and run the below commands to complete the task.

```
putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m c:\user\batchcommands.txt
```

**1st Command :**

```
cd/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/COLLECT/EOD/bin_arm
```

**2nd Command :**

```
./FileUpload.sh
```

**3rd Command :**

```
cd/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/COLLECT/EOD/bin_arm
```

**4th Command :**

```
./execute_eodarx.sh
```

How can I run these commands serially (completion of previous command)?

Answer (score 0):

Write all commands in file with extension *.bat for e.g. auto_script.bat

Bat file is like shell scripts in windows and runs command in synchronous way.

then

`putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -m "c: && cd path_to_file && auto_script "`

**Note : just use filename (of the bat file) as command in the directory.** [how to run bat file for cmd](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001668.htm)

Comment: Isn't plink better for this?