# How to launch an application using a command to run a batch file that starts the application?

Tags: c#, ssh, system-administration

Using SSH Net library, I need to send a command to run a batch file that launches an application. The issue is that if I create a simple batch file with the creation of a text file, everything works, but the application doesn't open. Thanks.

I've heard that it may be necessary to grant privileges to the user to work with the SSH service and create another user as a service for this all to work with the interface, but my knowledge in system administration is weak.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you will need to escalate permissions.. (just for test grand admin access, than you will revoke and adjust.)

```
SshCommand command = client.RunCommand("X:\process.bat");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not yield any results.

Comment: check this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856288/run-ssh-commands-in-batch-windows